# Update multiple records in db which are not already present in the table

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I get an `array()` of schools that a person attended. For the user `sarah@gmail.com`, the array has 3 `degree`s that she has earned. My table only has 2 of her 3 degrees.

What is the easiest way to insert Sarah's degrees not already present in the table?

Start Table:

```
email            school    degree 

d@d.com          Yale      BA
d@d.com          Emery     PHD
a@a.com          ClownU    BS
sarah@gmail.com  Harvard   BA
sarah@gmail.com  Harvard   Masters
```

End Table:

```
email            school    degree 

d@d.com          Yale      BA
d@d.com          Emery     PHD
a@a.com          ClownU    BS
sarah@gmail.com  Harvard   BA
sarah@gmail.com  Harvard   Masters
sarah@gmail.com  Harvard   PHD
```

Options I've considered:

1. Delete all of sarah's records. Reinsert all of sarah's records.
2. For each record, see if it exists. If it does, do nothing, else write the record.
3. **Some magical CI function** that updates_batch or inserts_batch if a particular record doesn't exist?

Comment: Does the table have a key (id) for the rows, and does it differ for existing elements that are in the array? If you had a key, and it was the same in the array and the database you may be able to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: good question i also follow 1 task. coz it is faster. i can make custom function but speed really matter

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert Into [Start-Table] (email, school, degree)
(
select b.email, b.school, b.degree from [End-Table] b 
where NOT EXISTS (Select email, school, degree from [Start-Table]
                  where email = b.email and school = b.school and degree = b.degree)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some how like you and i solved it like this:
1-Delete all Records of the user you want and than insert batch it like the code blow.

```
           $employer_office        = $this->input->post('employer_office');
            $emp_job_type           = $this->input->post('job_type');
            $job_title              = $this->input->post('job_title');
            $job_appointment_date   = $this->input->post('job_appointment_date');
            $job_duration           = $this->input->post('job_duration');
            $job_place              = $this->input->post('job_place');
            $type_of_relation       = $this->input->post('type_of_relation');
            $monthly_salary         = $this->input->post('monthly_salary');
            $remarks                = $this->input->post('remarks');

            $all_array = array();

            if($employer_office)
            {
                if(is_array($employer_office))
                {

                   for($j=0; $j<count($employer_office); $j++)
                   {


                       $form_arr   = array(
                                    'employer_office'      =>$employer_office[$j],
                                    'job_type'             =>$emp_job_type[$j],
                                    'job_title'            =>$job_title[$j],
                                    'job_appointment_date' =>change_datei($job_appointment_date[$j]),
                                    'job_duration'         =>$job_duration[$j],
                                    'job_place'            =>$job_place[$j],
                                    'type_of_relation'     =>$type_of_relation[$j],
                                    'monthly_salary'       =>$monthly_salary[$j],
                                    'remarks'              =>$remarks[$j],
                                    'regdate'              =>date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
                                    'userid'               =>$id
                                    );
                                    array_push($all_array, $form_arr);
                   }



                }
            }

            if($this->history_model->delete_all('ast_jobs_history',  $id)==TRUE)
            {
                if($this->history_model->all_insert('ast_jobs_history', $all_array)==TRUE)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("msg","<span class='m_success'>".$this->lang->line('global_update_success')."</span>");
                    redirect('history/home/list_dy','refresh');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("msg","<span class='m_error'>".$this->lang->line('global_update_error')."</span>");
                    redirect('history/home/list_dy','refresh');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('unauthorized');
            }
```

and inside the model insert_batch it.

```
        function all_insert($tbl, $data=array())
        {
            if(is_array($data))
            {
                $this->db->trans_start();
                $this->db->insert_batch($tbl,$data);
                $this->db->trans_complete();
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

bring some changes and i hope that this will give you a hint on how to solve your problem.

or you can also do a query if you don't want to delete your records of specific id,
get the data according to ID and use array_search() or in_array() function to filter your posted data and get the record you want to insert it and than insert it to database.

Comment: i also do same always

Answer (score 0):

If to keep the same ID for your records is not important, just delete and re-insert all the data. If you want to keep the same IDs for old records, you can also delete it but you have yo query the DB at first to get the IDs and create an array with them. Then you can insert all new data.

But if I were you I would create a function that looks up into the DB looking for existing records. If the record exists, it updates it. If not, it creates a new one. I think it's the cleanest way to solve this problem.